# JavaScript stops working when I compress my script

Tags: javascript, optimization, jscompress

I want to compress my 2000+ lines of javascript and I have tested both http://dean.edwards.name/packer/ and http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home.

But in both cases, the compressed script gives me errors.
An example of an error is `jQuery(document).Da is not a function`.

Why isn't my script working after optimization?
And what can I do to optimize / compress my script?

Comment: I don't think you'll receive an answer without posting the offending code snippet.

Comment: Have you used semi-colons throughout your script?

Comment: JSLint will help you find problems with your JS: http://www.jslint.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try an online YUI Compressor. This is the first result on google: http://www.refresh-sf.com/yui/

Comment: Thanks that worked. Obfuscating the code afterwards kind of kills the compression though :(

Comment: I tested obfuscating using this site: http://www.javascriptobfuscator.com/Default.aspx

Comment: Even if you're using YUI compressor, you can run into this problem, as I did. See my answer about semicolons. Changing the tool you're using might just be rearranging the files and will hide this problem, but it could crop up again next time you run YUI compressor.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you have a semicolon at the beginning of every JavaScript file. Bizarre, I know, but here's why:

You might have something like this in one file:

```
function someFunc() {
   ...
}
```

followed by something like this in the next file (this is how many jQuery plugins look):

```
(function($) {
   ...
})(jQuery);
```

That gets compressed into this:

```
function someFunc(){ }( function($){...} )(jQuery);
```

Which essentially calls `someFunc` with `function($){...}` as it's argument. Then, it will take whatever is returned, and assume it is a function and call it with `jQuery` as the argument.

This is why most jQuery plugins start with `;(function($){`.

Putting a semicolon at the beginning of every file (or the end, but make it consistent) will make your scripts look like:

```
;function someFunc(){ }; (function($){...})(jQuery);
```

That way, your scripts will be interpreted as intended.

Comment: You are a life saver man!
I wonder: Why some scripts do not follow this practice? Why we must edit their source code to simply add a semicolon?

Comment: @nik_m. I wonder why all concatenating tools don't add this for you.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problems. everytime i wanted to minify my javascript-files inclusive a few jquery-plugins i got an error.
first i tried to solve the problems with the addional semicolons as nicholaides explained in his last post. even with his advice i couldn't manage to minify my js-file without errors.
after that i changed the following line in every jquery-plugin and in worked for me;
for instance:

```
(function($) {
$.fn.defaultInputs = function(settings) { ...
```

i have simplified to

```
jQuery.fn.defaultInputs = function(settings) { ...
```